# Description of an Event in Special Relativity

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames

Let me set up a system, where we have a rocket, and an asteroid moving towards it. Event 1 : When asteroid appears on the Horizon ( crosses an arbitrary mark about 14 light minutes away ), Event 2 : When the asteroid comes and collides with the rocket. If we know the distance and time of each event with respect to rocket, we can use Lorentz transformation to find out the values for the asteroid perspective.

Now, say, we knew the values from the asteroid perspective, then using inverse lorentz transformation, we can get back our original values for the rocket. However, what an  inverse transformation really is, is that we are considering the asteroid at rest and the rocket to be moving.

My question is, if I look at the inverse lorentz transform as a separate lorentz transformation with negative velocity, how would I define my events in this new problem. I know how I can get the coordinates and all. But is there any way, special relativity gives me idea on how the event is defined here ? Like does event 1 become appearance of rocket on a mark set by the asteroid or something like that ? What would be the physical description of an event after I change my perspective. How will someone on the asteroid, describe the event ( not saying coordinates. )

EDIT : Added my working:

It had been provided that distance from the rockets perspective was 14.4 lt-min, and time at wich collision takes place is 60 min.

[image]
[image]

( Note: I have no problem with the math, more like understanding/accepting the implications )

The math tells me that event 1 happens at 14.4 lt min according to rocket and at 14.834 according to the asteroid. Event 2 happens at 0 according to rocket and again at 14.834 according to the rocket. It doesn't matter if the objects approach each other from left or from right.

( *In the second case, I've drawn the diagram considering the rocket is approaching from the left, but I've done the math as if it is approaching from the right. This should just flip the signs of x initial and x final, but ultimately doesn't change the sum.* )

I'm just asking, shouldn't the event have taken place at the origin of the asteroid frame, if the asteroid itself is causing the event ? Like it is defined that way right ? Intuitively I don't see how the events are happening at 14.834 or -14.834 from the rocket's perspective.

Comment: Event 1 is _not_ an event; it is observer dependent.  Event 2 is OK.  Suggest you reconsider and edit your question.

Comment: What do you mean by "appears on the horizon " ? The way you have phrased it , the event refers to the light from the asteroid hitting the eyes of the observer

Comment: @silverrahul  I've redefined the first event. The horizon is an arbitrary mark set by the rocket. When the asteroid crosses this mark, the rocket people consider to be the first event.

Comment: @NakshatraGangopadhay Then what is the issue ? That is the first event then.

Comment: @silverrahul I'm just wondering, how the asteroid will physically describe these events in a meaningful way. If the rocket defines events based on the movement of the asteroid, how will the asteroid define these events ? I'm not talking about coordinates, just a physical description from the asteroid perspective.

Comment: @NakshatraGangopadhay In the asteroid perspective, the event will be the asteroid crossing that mark as well, as you have defined the event that way

Comment: @ yes, that is what I thought too. But the problem was, this was part of a question, and when you solve it, you get the distance of both events in the asteroids perspective to be 14.9 light min, and from the rockets perspective event 1 happens at 14. lt min, and event 2 at the origin. You get this using the transformation. Distance between the events from the asteroids perspective is 0 as expected. But they don't happen at the origin of asteroid frame. But if the asteroid describes the event as itself moving past a horizon, shouldn't both events happen at the origin of the asteroid frame ?

Comment: In the asteroid frame, it should be stationary, and the mark should come towards it. So, shouldn't both events take place at the origin ? In the rocket frame, event 1 happens at 14.4 lt min, and event 2 at 0 lt min. using transformation, I'm getting the location of these two events in asteroid frame to be 14.9 lt min, instead of the origin 0. In both cases distance between the events is 0, so that is not a problem

Comment: You might have made some mistake , i cannot say anything unless you show me the details of this problem

Comment: @silverrahul basically I know the location of two events from rocket's perspective. I used the transformation to find the locations from the asteroid perspective. Now, since the asteroid is causing the event, the separation of events in the asteroid perspective should be 0, and I got that correct. Its just the location of this event. Intuitively I think these events should take place at the origin of the asteroid frame, but the math gives me something else. I've added my working for you to verify. Forgive the rough nature and lack of rigour.  I just need to see how my intuition is wrong.

Comment: How did you do xf' = 14.834 and xi'=14.834  in page 4 near the top ?

Comment: Do you hav enough reputatio to talk in chatroom for extended  conversation ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124595/discussion-between-nakshatra-gangopadhay-and-silverrahul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application of lorentz formula is questionable. You cannot use it blindly.

Remember the standard lorentz formula is for 2 frames, that have t=t' = 0 at the moment when they cross over . The formula works for that situation.

Here S and S' are not crossing over at t=t'=0. SO, you cannot blindly apply that formula